# Issue while putting data in array variable

Tags: php, arrays

I am putting the data from backend to an array variable. But its skipping some value while checking condition in function `in_array()`.

```
$check_empp=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from customer");
while($check_emp_fetchh=mysqli_fetch_array($check_empp,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $ecustomercheck[]=$check_emp_fetchh['customer_id'];
}

if (in_array($value[0], $ecustomercheck)) {        
    $unique_array[] = array('cid'=>$value[0], 'rep_name'=>$value[2], 'date'=>$value[1]);
}
print_r($unique_array);
```

The `$value[0]` includes the values of customer id's ('SLR-84936878','SLR-84963110'). The "$unique_array" array varible skipping some compared existing values. It's working fine if i am taking an custom array variable and initialising values into it. Like:

```
$check_empp=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from customer");
while($check_emp_fetchh=mysqli_fetch_array($check_empp,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $ecustomercheck[]=$check_emp_fetchh['customer_id'];
}

$ac=array('SLR-84936878','SLR-84963110','SLR-76472164','SLR-76472174','SLR-14936878','SLR-25936878');

if (in_array($value[0], $ac)) {    
    $unique_array[] = array('cid'=>$value[0], 'rep_name'=>$value[2], 'date'=>$value[1]);
}

print_r($unique_array);
```

Working fine like that above. But I want to work it with fetch data from the database. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where u define this `$value[0]` ? or `$value` this will work `if (in_array('SLR-84936878', $ac))`

Comment: yes excatly. its coming from the top loop. i have edited the question. the `$value[0]` holds the customer id's. It will have the duplicate customer id's, so that i am checking the condition there and putting values into the `$unique_array` varibale.

Comment: check this array `print_r($ecustomercheck)`

Comment: it's a just array variable, my issue is with array varibale those i am fetching from database. At the time of comparing with `in_array` function its skipping some value.

Comment: it has all the appropriate values those exists in the database. but issue occurs at the time of comparing with in_array function.

Comment: I thing it may be because of PHP parser issue. It can be solved with some trick. I am not too much efficient into it.

Comment: `if (in_array($value[0], $ecustomercheck)) {        
   echo true;
}else{echo false;}` i think your `in_array()` is working

Comment: yes in_array is working. But giving appropriate result with the `$ac` array variable. But its skipping value with `$ecustomercheck` array varibale.

Comment: can u share the result of `print_r($ecustomercheck)`

Comment: its giving `Array ( [0] => SLR-84936878 [1] => SLR-84963110 [2] => SLR-76472164 [3] => SLR-76472174 [4] => SLR-14936878 [5] => SLR-25936878 ) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124617/discussion-between-devpro-and-junkk-rr).

Comment: choose the best answer and mark as accepted this will help to others

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$ac` you should use the `$ecustomercheck`:

```
$check_empp=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from customer");
while($check_emp_fetchh=mysqli_fetch_array($check_empp,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $ecustomercheck[]=$check_emp_fetchh['customer_id'];
}

if (in_array($value[0], $ecustomercheck)) {
    $unique_array[] = array('cid'=>$value[0], 'rep_name'=>$value[2], 'date'=>$value[1]);
}
print_r($unique_array);
```

**EDIT:**

I just make my own array if my understanding is right:

```
$check_empp=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from customer");
while($check_emp_fetchh=mysqli_fetch_array($check_empp,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $ecustomercheck[]=$check_emp_fetchh['customer_id'];
}

$a = array(array("SLR-84936878","05/25/2016", "SAMSUNG"),array("SLR-84963110","05/27/2016", "APPLE")) ;

foreach($a as $value) {
    if (in_array($value[0], $ecustomercheck)) {
        $unique_array[] = array('cid'=>$value[0], 'rep_name'=>$value[2], 'date'=>$value[1]);
    }   
}

print_r($unique_array);
```

Comment: Please help if you have any solution. The array varibale initialize from database is not properly working, its skipping some values.

Comment: Yep, he edited the question. By the way, as @devpro said, what is the result of your print_r($value); and also the print_r($ecustomercheck);

Comment: $value is coming from the foreach loop. like `foreach ($a as $value) { }` and it has the three column values as cid, date and representative name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing array in `$unique_array` as:

```
$unique_array[] = array('cid'=>$value[0], 'rep_name'=>$value[2], 'date'=>$value[1]);
```

*You can just store data in `$unqiue_array` like that:*

```
<?php

$unique_array = array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($a as $value)
{
  if (in_array(trim($value[0]), $ecustomercheck))
  {
    $unique_array[$i]['cid'] = $value[0];
    $unique_array[$i]['rep_name'] = $value[1];
    $unique_array[$i]['date'] = $value[2];    
  }  
  $i++;
}
print_r($unique_array);
?>
```